# How to send and read mail using Microsoft graph api (python-o365) in Python Django using web app based authentication?

Tags: python, django, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

I am new to using Microsoft Graph API for office 365 integration. I have gone through the official documentation at https://github.com/O365/python-o365 and I am able to implement mail send and mail read using console stuff.

Code is below:

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('5ed870b6-efee-41bb-83cf-1234567890', '6a~4o-F_2~z__n97iaNAG7f7r_1234567890')
account = Account(credentials)
if account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all']):
   print('Authenticated!')
```

Here it asks for url to copy and paste done, then I can

```
def readMail(convId, account):
    mailbox = account.mailbox()
    test_mailbox = mailbox.get_folder(folder_name="Inbox")
    query = mailbox.new_query().on_attribute('conversation_id').equals(convId)
    listOfMails = []
    for message in test_mailbox.get_messages(limit=100, query=query, batch=20):
        mail_time = message.received
        # print(mail_time)
        mail_ID = message.internet_message_id
        mail_sender = message.sender
        mail_cc = message.cc
        mail_subject = message.subject
        mail_content = message.get_body_text()
        mail_dict = {'mail_time': mail_time, 'mail_ID': mail_ID, 'mail_sender': mail_sender, 'mail_cc': mail_cc,
                     'mail_subject': mail_subject, 'mail_content': mail_content}
        listOfMails.append(mail_dict)
    lastMail = listOfMails[len(listOfMails) - 1]
    # print(len(listOfMails))
    return lastMail

convId = 'AAQkAGFiYTcwOWM1LTgwNWQtNDk0Ny1hY2I0LWRjNTM2NTVjMmFhMgAQAO_HWbiF8xtLtpSPxMKOGtA='
lastMail = readMail(convId, account)

print(lastMail)


def sendMail(lastMail, account):
    mail_id = lastMail.get('mail_ID')
    mailbox = account.mailbox()
    test_mailbox = mailbox.get_folder(folder_name="Inbox")
    query = mailbox.new_query().on_attribute('internet_message_id').contains(mail_id)  # see Query object in Utils
    for message in test_mailbox.get_messages(1, query=query):
        # print("dsdsdf")
        print(message.get_body_text())
        message.mark_as_read()
        reply_msg = message.reply()
        reply_msg.body = 'Sorry Its just a Test Mail !'
        reply_msg.attachments.add('C:/Users/geetanjali.sharma/Pictures/Screenshots/Sabbatical_Fail/Screenshot (16).png')
        reply_msg.send()

sendMail(lastMail, account)
```

But when I try to do the same thing with Web app based authentication interface.

My code:

```
from O365 import Account,FileSystemTokenBackend
import os
credentials = ('7c00f426-2ac5-486f-a137-1234567890', 'cOtN3a4_e.dv0WNF0.qN.xx5wgF42Tu.10.')

token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path=os.getcwd()+'/token_folder/', token_filename='my_token.txt')
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='3d4f5678b727a530-a0d5-4fb8-bd40-d8f9763e97db',token_backend=token_backend)
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')
   m = account.new_message()
   m.to.add('someone@someone.com')
   m.subject = 'Testing!'
   m.body = "George Best quote: I've stopped drinking, but only while I'm asleep."
   m.send()
```

i get error

```
Authenticated!
Client Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sendMail | Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'sendMail'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ntl/Documents/projects/dataIngestionApp/dataingestionBackend/dataIngestionML/send_mail.py", line 13, in <module>
    m.send()
  File "/home/ntl/anaconda3/envs/dataai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/O365/message.py", line 694, in send
    response = self.con.post(url, data=data)
  File "/home/ntl/anaconda3/envs/dataai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/O365/connection.py", line 811, in post
    return self.oauth_request(url, 'post', data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ntl/anaconda3/envs/dataai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/O365/connection.py", line 789, in oauth_request
    return self._internal_request(self.session, url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ntl/anaconda3/envs/dataai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/O365/connection.py", line 751, in _internal_request
    raise HTTPError('{} | Error Message: {}'.format(e.args[0], error_message), response=response) from None
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sendMail | Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'sendMail'.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also adding my apps permission in azure

[image]

Comment: Your request endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sendMail` is wrong. The correct endpoint should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail`. Please check `account.new_message()` method.

Comment: from where to change it , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the resource for the message.

```
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id=tenant_id)
m = account.mailbox(resource='{the email address of sender}')
```

Comment: Hi already tried
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')
   m = account.new_message(resource='rajnish.3.kumar@xxx.com')
   m.to.add('geetanjali.sharma@xxx.com')
   m.subject = 'Testing!'
   m.body = "George Best quote: I've stopped drinking, but only while I'm asleep."
   m.send()

Comment: but still getting Client Error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/rajnish.3.kumar@niit-tech.com/sendMail | Error Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.
Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.

Comment: i can see as per your previous comment you asked endpoint should be https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail , now i can see my endpoint as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/rajnish.3.kumar@niit-tech.com/sendMail, its missiing ID, from where to get ID

Comment: @eduliant It doesn't matter. You can use `rajnish.3.kumar@niit-tech.com` as the `userPrincipalName` here. Can you check your permissions configured in Azure AD app? And decode your access token in https://jwt.io. Please add some screenshots of them.

Comment: Hi allen added screenshot

Comment: @eduliant You are using client_credentials flow here. So you should add Application permissions rather than Delegated permissions. And the Application permission 
`Mail.Send` requires admin consent. But it seems that you are not the admin of your tenant based on your screenshot. You should use an admin account or ask admin do consent for you.

Comment: ok, but getting Application permissions will be hard , is there a way by which i can use delegated permission

Comment: ok i will try to get admin conset , one thing can you confirm to read also do i need admin conset

Comment: @eduliant If you want to use delegated permission, you need to use 'authorization' as the `auth_flow_type`. Based on https://github.com/O365/python-o365#authentication-steps, the "When authenticating on behalf of a user:" part: `from O365 import Account
credentials = ('my_client_id', 'my_client_secret')

# the default protocol will be Microsoft Graph
# the default authentication method will be "on behalf of a user"

account = Account(credentials)`, this will use default authentication method will be "on behalf of a user", saying that delegated permission.

Comment: HI allen when i do that as you said from O365 import Account
credentials = ('7c00f426-2ac5-486f-a137-8d75963b98eb', 'cOtN3a4_u.dv0WNF0.qN.xx5wgF42Tu.2.')

account = Account(credentials)
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')
   m = account.new_message(resource='rajnish.3.kumar@xxx.com')
   m.to.add('geetanjali.sharma@xxx.com')
   m.subject = 'Testing!'
   m.body = "George Best quote: I've stopped drinking, but only while I'm asleep."
   m.send()  it gives error ValueError: The scopes are not set. Define the scopes requested., sorry if i have misintepreted

Comment: @eduliant As I have suggested, please github.com/O365/python-o365#authentication-steps, the "When authenticating on behalf of a user:" part. It gives an example for delegated permission. What you need to do is to add the scope: `if account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all']):
   print('Authenticated!')`.

Comment: hi when i do that from O365 import Account
credentials = ('7c00f426-2ac5-486f-a137-8d75963b98eb', 'cOtN3a4_u.dv0WNF0.qN.xx5wgF42Tu.2.')
account = Account(credentials)


if account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all']):
    print('Authenticated!')  , in console i can see Visit the following url to give consent: some url, and paste the url

Comment: @eduliant You can copy that url and access it from a browser. Log in with your Azure account. And do the consent as a user(if you are not an admin).

Comment: hi thanks for the help, this was working for me in the first place , but i dont want this copy paste thing as i have to implement it in an application, thats why i was looking for a way by which i can skip this copy paste

Comment: @eduliant It only requires you to do this consent the first time you log in to the application. Learn more about user consent here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent. If an admin of your tenant can do the admin consent, the consent workflow won't popup for any other users.

Comment: ok if u r suggesting a copy paste for the first time but i will host this code on a server hosted on a url, user will access the url, so for them i need to trap the url and open it in a browser, do authentication there and again trap the authenticated url and paste it in the console using code, please suggest what your thoughts are on this , is there a way by which i can trap these urls show that i can opene a pop up window for authorization

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215794/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-eduliant).